# puppet apt-get update only once before anything else?

Tags: vagrant, puppet, apt-get

I know the basics of ordering in puppet to run apt-get update before a specific package but would like to specify to just run apt-get update only once and then execute the rest of the puppet file. Is that possible?

All of the ways listed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845864/puppet-trick-run-apt-get-update-before-installing-other-packages) need to either run apt-get before every package or use arrows or requires to specify each package.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This would be my recommendation from that list:

```
exec { "apt-update":
    command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update"
}

Exec["apt-update"] -> Package <| |>
```

This will ensure that the exec is run before **any** package, not that the exec is run before **each** package. In fact, any resource in puppet will only ever be *executed at most once per puppet run*.

But if you're wanting the exec to occur before ANY type of resource I guess you could do something like:

```
exec { "apt-update":
    command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update",
    before  => Stage["main"],
}
```

The "main" Stage is the default stage for each resource, so this would make the exec occur before anything else.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thank you Sekm. I was misunderstanding how it worked and thinking if there are 5 packages for example then it would run apt-get update 5 times. Thank you for explaining it and also for the second option as it could come in handy for other things.

Answer (score 3):

With [puppetlabs-apt](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt) module, it should be enough to define dependency on the module for any package that will be installed:

```
Class['apt::update'] -> Package <| provider == 'apt' |>
```

This assumes basic configuration of `apt`, e.g.:

```
class { 'apt':
    update => {
      frequency => 'daily',
    },
    purge => {
      'sources.list' => false,
      'sources.list.d' => true,
    },
  }
```

Comment: This is the better answer; it's the one recommended in the Puppet docs, and it avoids having to manually specify a command to exec.

Comment: After doing that, when running `pdk test unit` I get `dependency cycles found: (Package[gnupg] => Class[Apt] => Package[gnupg])` and tests fail