# PuPHPet Vagrant box needs apt-get update?

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, puppet, apt, puphpet

I'm trying to use a PuPHPet vagrant machine.

I haven't customized it at all other than through what the gui offers and yet it doesn't want to provision - I'm getting the below errors:

If I ssh into the machine and run the command then I get the same output - but it can be fixed by first running a `sudo apt-get update` before running the command - So my question is how can I fix this so I can provision correctly?

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install software-properties-common' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python3-pycurl python3-software-properties unattended-upgrades
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python3-pycurl-dbg bsd-mailx mail-transport-agent
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-pycurl python3-software-properties software-properties-common
  unattended-upgrades
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 102 kB of archives.
After this operation, 800 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main python3-pycurl amd64 7.19.3-0ubuntu3 [47.5 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main unattended-upgrades all 0.82.1ubuntu2 [25.5 kB]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main python3-software-properties all 0.92.37.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main software-properties-common all 0.92.37.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Fetched 73.0 kB in 1s (43.5 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/python3-software-properties_0.92.37.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.92.37.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

config.yaml

```
---
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
        hostname: ''
        memory: '512'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: ''
            forwarded_port:
                T16mszwd41ah:
                    host: '8080'
                    guest: '80'
                PUPPfErpEhrT:
                    host: '8081'
                    guest: '81'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            evPDlxHH6zhd:
                source: ./
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                    auto: 'false'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: null
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - expires
        - headers
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        NtvOi2foVuXj:
            servername: 127.0.0.1
            docroot: /var/www/public
            port: '80'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    vhosts:
        orNIgNk92NIk:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome
            listen_port: '80'
            location: \.php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '55'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
    timezone: Pacific/Auckland
    mod_php: 0
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        port: '9000'
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
    timezone: null
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 6.3.0
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        sGFuU5QHAYrD:
            version: ''
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
python:
    install: '0'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
mysql:
    install: '1'
    root_password: vagrant
    adminer: 0
    databases:
        jZwlMnxwUqCO:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: vagrant
            host: localhost
            user: vagrant
            password: vagrant
            sql_file: ''
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
mailcatcher:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: '1'
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        java_install: true
        autoupgrade: true
```

Comment: Related? Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845864/puppet-trick-run-apt-get-update-before-installing-other-packages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed here by a commit made today: https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/commit/6ce872c9be802460cc3879d5531ddc8e0471c36c

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is edit file **puphpet/shell/initial-setup.sh** and comment the following line:

```
if [[ -f '/.puphpet-stuff/initial-setup-base-packages' ]]; then
    exit 0
fi
```

And run `vagrant provision` again, it worked for me.